# Looping thru Mongo database with Node.js and Handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js

I'm new to programming and am learning Javascript and Node.js. I am looking for some help on how to pull some data from my database. I have a Mongo database with a list of job positions, there is a bool condition that is part of that each job that is called active. I am trying to loop thru the data and only display data where the active bool is set to true.

I was able to get to a point where I am able to loop thru and display all job postions, but now need help with an if statement to display on active jobs.

Below is what I have to display all my positions.

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

/* GET addjob page. */
router.get('/addjob', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('addjob', { title: 'Express' });
});

/* GET joblist page. */
router.get('/joblist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('usercollection');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
    res.render('joblist', {
            "joblist" : docs
    });
 });
});


module.exports = router;
```

joblist.hbs

```
{{#each joblist}}
  <div>
  {{jobtitle}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define conditions the documents needs to match in the initial request to mongo as well.
If you only want the active docs then it saves you the reduce operation.

```
router.get('/joblist', function(req, res) {
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.get('usercollection');
  collection.find({active: true},function(e,docs){
    res.render('joblist', {
      "joblist" : docs
    });
  });
});
```